# domain name in dhcp

Tags: dhcp, linux

My os is ubuntu and I use virtualbox and I have xp on that. now I want to set my **ubuntu** to **dhcp server**. So I downloaded **isc-dhcp-server** on ubuntu in configuration file i see these two line are not comment

**option domain-name "example.org";**

**option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;**

So what I should write in **example.org** or **ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;**
Can I comment them or better to say am I need them for my very simple scenario which xp just give its ip address from ubuntu.

Comment: ooh is there any link to say what kind of question we can ask in this stack. I really need that

Comment: Yes, it's actually linked on the 'ask a question page': https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this field is not neccessary but you could put it to refer to the Name of the NameServer(DNS) you want to assign to the client of DHCP plus to the IP

usually we set the Name Server of google:

```
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
```